# What is the good practice to instantiate page object in POM and PageObjectFactory?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, page-objects, selenium3, page-factory

I am practising POM and Page Object factory. I would like to learn good practices in instantiating the pages.

till now I am Instantiating the pages from test class (e.g. TC_01_Register.java) using the below statement, I am not passing driver object to page class

```
OCHomePage ochome = PageFactory.initElements(wdriver,OCHomePage.class);
```

another way I was thinking is, creating the class object where Page class receives the constructor and instantiate the page factory in constructor itself

```
OCHomePage ochome = new OCHomePage(wdriver);
```

OCHomePage class (code snippet)

```
public OCHomePage {
    OCHomePage (WebDriver wdriver){
        PageFactory.initElements(wdriver,this.class)
   }
  @findby... // code continues ..
}
```

please suggest me if any other best ways available or the practices you follow..

Comment: A third method is to add a factory method to the page object, that accepts the webDriver, creates the page object and initialises its elements.  When a page navigates using a click it can use the factory method.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are fine, but you can improve it in two ways:

- Abstract the creation to a [setup method on the test class](https://dzone.com/articles/testng-beforemethod-annotation), assuming each class is related to each application page.
- Abstract the factory initiation (and other common steps) to a base class:

  ```
  public OCHomePage extends BasePage {
      OCHomePage (WebDriver wdriver){
          super(wdriver);
      }
  }

  public BasePage {
      BasePage (WebDriver wdriver){
          PageFactory.initElements(wdriver,this.class);
      }
  }
  ```